# VBA Transpose From Specific Number of Cells Above

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, transpose, excel-r1c1-notation

I've been working on a VBA code, this is only a minor part of my project for reviewing accounting transactions.

The code not included inserts blank rows where there have been transactions using multiple account names. I want to transpose the multiple account names on each transactions where necessary. The "RowNum" code references the number count of account names on that particular transaction. I was hoping to insert that number into my FormulaR1C1.

```
Sub cellnum()
 
RowNum = "=R[-1]C[4]"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=transpose(R[-" & RowNum.Value & "C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1])"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `RowNum = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Value`?

Comment: That worked!! Thanks you!

Comment: Is there a way I can offset from where the formula is being input and not from my active cell?

Comment: Aren't `ActiveCell` and the formula cell the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the formula in a different cell than the active cell you need to set the range for that cell first.

for example something like should give the right result

```
Set rng = Range("A1") 
rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=transpose(R[-" & RowNum.Value & "C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1])"
```

Im new to VBA and still learning but I think this is the way to go.